# Replication from mysql 5.1 to mariadb 10.0

Tags: replication

I have replicated my db on mysql 5.1 to mariadb 10.0. I have installed mariadb 10.0 on slave server, take the backup on mysql 5.1 , transferred the backup on slave server having mariadb 10.0. and setup replication. Everything goes well. But slave stuck at delete_row_event .
I made RCA and found that  there was some type of data mismatch on this table. Below is the structure of the table:

CREATE TABLE `gsf` (
  `data_on_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `record_timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `WAODate` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CardNbr` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TranAmt` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `TranCode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InvoiceNbr` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MerNo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BatchNo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GoeRefNum` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GoeOrderID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `InvoiceNbr` (`InvoiceNbr`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
I

I though that this may be due to some mis-configuration of  replication at my end. So, I decided just to take the dump of this table and restore it.
Then, I dropped the table from the slave and take the complete dump of only this table from master and store in the slave. But here also I faced the same problem. Data was not identical here which I was not expecting this time.

On master, I executed:

mysql> select record_timestamp  from gsf where record_timestamp=1443078738;
Empty set, 1 warning (0.38 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                       |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Incorrect datetime value: '1443078738' for column 'record_timestamp' at row 1 |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

On the slave, I executed the same query and it returns,

record_timestamp    |
+---------------------+
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
10 rows in set, 1 warning (0.29 sec)

show warnings;
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Incorrect datetime value: '1443078738' |

I think a configuration variable on mariadb 10 is effecting my data.

Please help me in this regard.

Is creating slave from mysql 5.1 to mariadb 10.0 is feasible?

Answer (score 0):

[TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) fields expect to be in the format '2015-09-24 07:12:18'. This is why you get warnings in both MySQL and MariaDB. Run the query with the correct formatting and the results will be the same for both DB's - assuming the import also didn't have warnings.

Use [FROM_UNIXTIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) to convert from seconds since 1970 to the timestamp format:

```
 SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME('1443078738') AS `timestamp`;

 timestamp
 .........
 2015-09-24 07:12:18
```

As I understand it, MySQL and Maria are not committed to remaining compatible. I wouldn't be surprised if there were binary log incompatibilities. Could you test with a newer version of MySQL or an older MariaDB version.